# Android getContentResolver() Using “IN” with a WHERE clause with large number of Items

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver

Android getContentResolver() Using “IN” in a WHERE clause with large number of Items

I have Implemented this query success fully and It gives the required data

```
 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String projection[] = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                    // android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,};
                String selection1 = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1" + " AND "
                   + MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " IN(";
            for (int i = 0; i < SongsList.size(); i++) {// songslist is an array of IDs
                selection1 += "?, ";
            }
            selection1 = selection1.substring(0, selection1.length() - 2) + ")";

            String[] selectionArgs = new String[SongsList.size()];
            selectionArgs = SongsList.toArray(selectionArgs);

            Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection1,
                    selectionArgs, null);
```

However when the number of Items is large the query fails,

Is there an alternative to retrieve Large number of Items with getContentResolver() without using “IN” in a WHERE clause

Comment: Why not using `AsyncTask` to execute query in Work Thread?

Comment: can u provide an example with asynctask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SQL, the proper way to handle a large number of IDs would be to put them into a temporary table, and join that with the media table.
But with a content provider, you do not have access to that database, so this is not possible.

Your best bet is to retrieve all rows, and then ignore any that do not have one of your IDs.

Alternatively, retrieve the rows one by one. (This probably has too much overhead.)

(If you need the filtered results as an actual `Cursor` object, put them into a
[MatrixCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).)

Comment: I will take that as an accepted answer, logically  works good, but still there should be some better management for android